# How to process range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write a function in excel. If I have 5 values it should return the mean of the values, if any value is less than 0 should not be counted towards mean. So far I know how to process one value, but I don't how to process if range is passed for example

=process_myfunction(A1:A10)

Comment: `=averageif()`  define your range, make the ciriteria ">=0"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Function process_myfunction(rng As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rngCnt As Long, rngSum As Long

    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.Value >= 0 Then           'check if cell value > 0
            rngSum = rngSum + cel.Value 'sum cell value
            rngCnt = rngCnt + 1         'count cell value
        End If
    Next cel
    process_myfunction = rngSum / rngCnt 'calculate mean
End Function
```

[image]

If you are using this UDF for non contiguous range then write function as

```
=process_myfunction((B2:B5,E2:E4,H2))
```

[image]